# Bootstrap responsive nav button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried countless threads but cannot get my bootstrap nav menu to drop down when converting it to word press theme for mobile/tablet.

**my nav code is**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg fixed-top logo">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="<?php bloginfo(template_directory); ?>/resources/images/Logo-blue-copy.png" ></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
<?php
      wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location'  => 'primary',
  'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
  'container'       => 'div',
  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
  'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
  'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
  'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
  'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
) );



?>      
    </nav>
```

**My jquery from bootstrap CDN currently in the footer..**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**my function file contains**

```
 <?php register_nav_menus( $locations ); 

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
 require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';

wp_register_script( 'jQuery', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js", null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

wp_register_script( 'jQuery', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js", null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

wp_register_script( 'jQuery', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js", null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');


?>

<?php register_nav_menus( $locations ); 

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';

?>
```

Some help would be fantastic. thanks.

Comment: *"My jquery from bootstrap CDN currently in the footer.."* .. I don't see jQuery

Comment: shouldve added this     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you must use 'walker'=> new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() without comma att end

```
  <?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location'  => 'primary',
  'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
  'container'       => 'div',
  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
  'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
  'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
  'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
  'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
) );
```

Comment: I think the problem is on registering the scrips to make to jquery do the drop down, the menu is working fine and showing the hamburger just not dropping down.

Comment: Mmm can you try to use CDN in your footer or any place you wanna work with,, without reqistration in your function.php

Answer (score 0):

**I have sussed it** - the problem was in the

'container_id'    => 'navbarsExampleDefault', (in the header.php file)

set as the above fixed it after checking the static version of the site using dev tools.